# Can't affect items within two divs with same class

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs with same class, and I want to add a certain class to the first 2 or 3 divs within that container div.

The problem is, I always affect the first div, but can't get it to affect the second div as well (the divs within the second parent div).

```
if ($('.uber-single').length) {
        $('.uber-single').each(function() {
            $('.uber-single .person:lt(3)').addClass('ntp');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your selector inside `each` is wrong:

```
$('.uber-single').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.person:lt(3)').addClass('ntp');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

try this without each ...

```
$('.uber-single').find('.person:lt(3)').addClass('ntp');
```

Answer (score 0):

this should fix your problem:

```
if ($('.uber-single').length) {
        $('.uber-single').each(function() {
            $(this).children('.person:lt(3)').each(function(){
                $(this).addClass('ntp');
            });
        });
    }
```